# PHP date format with concatenated text

Tags: php, datetime, format, concatenation

I am trying to format a date and time in PHP. I want the format to go as follows: May 15, 2014 at 9:15 AM. I've gotten everything to work except the word "at". How would I concatenate the word "at" between the date and time? Thanks.

```
<?php echo date('F j, Y g:i A',strtotime($editRow['user_create_date'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the literal characters:

```
<?php echo date('F j, Y \a\t g:i A',strtotime($editRow['user_create_date'])); ?>
```

[**See it in action here**](http://3v4l.org/ZmoTJ)

Comment: A little addition to this, any character NOT used by the `date()` function is displayed as is. If you need to use a character already assigned by the function it needs to be escaped as the example above.